# Make sequential fadeIn() promises more manageable

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparative-review, promise

I've two versions of promise code. The [page](http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/kzrgdvvc/2/) is a simple one - an unordered list with a few items. I am trying to make the items show up (`fadeIn`) one-after-another sequentially. This exercise is done to sort of explain people what promises are...

**Version 1:**

```
$('li').hide();

var fadeInFunc = function (obj) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    obj.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};

var funcWrapper = function (obj) {
    return function(){
        return fadeInFunc(obj);
    };
};

$('input').click(function () {
    fadeInFunc($('#li1'))
        .then(funcWrapper($('#li2')))
        .then(funcWrapper($('#li3')));
});
```

**Version 2:**

```
$('li').hide();

var fadeInFunc = function (obj) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    obj.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred;
};

var execute = function () {
    return fadeInFunc(this);
};

$('input').click(function () {
    fadeInFunc($('#li1'))
        .then(execute.bind($('#li2')))
        .then(execute.bind($('#li3')));
});
```

Both work fine. However, I want someone to dive in and try to understand the code better. Moreover, this code becomes unmanageable when you have variable number of `li` elements.

Here is the version for variable number of `li` elements:

```
var liCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
$('p').html('liCount: ' + liCount);
var ul = $('ul');
for(var i = 0; i< liCount; i++){
    ul.append('<li>Item ' + (i+1) + '</li>');
}
var liArray = $('li').hide();

var fadeInFunc = function (obj) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    obj.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred;
};

var funcWrapper = function(o){
    return function() { return fadeInFunc(o); };
};

$('input').click(function () {
    var prev;
    liArray.each(function(idx, obj){
        var o = $(obj);
        if(idx === 0){
            prev = fadeInFunc(o);
        }
        else{
            prev = prev.then(funcWrapper(o));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need promises for this one. [Here's an overly simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/kzrgdvvc/4/) that takes advantage of the fact that you can call the containing function by a given name.

```
// Let's turn a jQuery set to an array coz it doesn't have shift, which we'll use
var liArray = $('li').hide().get();

$('input').click(function handle(){
  // Unqueue one from the set and fade it in. Note that shift() alters the array so
  // the next time we call it, the second one is in front of the queue. Also wrapping
  // what we shifted with jQuery because get() returns an array of DOM elements of 
  // the jQuery set
  var li = $(liArray.shift());

  // If we shifted out nothing, then that's the end of this.
  if(!li) return;

  // Set the callback of the fadeIn to the same function. That way, if the animation
  // completes, then it fires again.
  li.fadeIn(handle);
});
```

If the idea is to teach promises, then the following might be better. [Here's an interesting approach](http://jsfiddle.net/kzrgdvvc/5/) where we use `Array.prototype.reduce` to carry over a dummy deferred, attach the handlers and kick it off, starting the fadeIn process.

```
var liArray = $('li').hide().get();

// So here we create a deferred object and during its creation, fade in the element.
// When the animation completes, it calls on `deferred.resolve` which resolves the
// fade promise.
function fade(item) {
  return $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
    $(item).fadeIn(deferred.resolve);
  }).promise();
}

// Here we use reduce to attach a handler for each item as well as allow us to carry
// over a value to the next iteration - the result value of `then()`.
function reducer(promise, item) {
  return promise.then(function () {
    return fade(item);
  });
}


// Here we create a dummy promise which allows our reducer to attach the handlers. 
// Then we use reduce to attach a handler for each item on the promise and then kick
// of the whole operation by resolving the dummy promise.
$('input').click(function handle() {
  var root = $.Deferred();
  liArray.reduce(reducer, root.promise());
  root.resolve();
});
```

Both examples assume `liArray` is an array containing `li` elements, whether dynamically generated or just fetched from the page, either way it doesn't matter as long as they're already rendered. Also went for an array instead of a jQuery object because array operations like `shift()` and `reduce()` are very handy.